# Apple Sandbox denying access to public data in low level calls

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, monomac

For some reason the sandbox on Lion is causing my app to crash while making a call to `getprotobyname` which should be available since it only reads static data provided by OSX itself.

Is this some kind of bug on Lion? Is there a reason why this would be forbidden by the sandbox? Seems like a very common method to be called.

```
OfficeDrop Sync(1568) deny file-read-data /private/etc/protocols

Process:         OfficeDrop Sync [1568]
Path:            /Users/some-user/Downloads/OfficeDrop Sync.app/Contents/MacOS/OfficeDrop Sync
Load Address:    0x1000
Identifier:      OfficeDrop Sync
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [125]

Date/Time:       2013-03-04 14:02:50.897 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G63)
Report Version:  7

Backtrace:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib            0x9c7e771e __open_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x96d6edc3 fopen$UNIX2003 + 90
2   libsystem_info.dylib              0x91352b4d _fsi_get_name_number_aliases + 123
3   libsystem_info.dylib              0x91351c2d file_protocol_byname + 44
4   libsystem_info.dylib              0x9135c0e8 search_protocol_byname + 69
5   libsystem_info.dylib              0x91357921 getprotobyname + 59
6   OfficeDrop Sync                   0x001b26c4 ves_icall_System_Net_Sockets_Socket_SetSocketOption_internal + 100
7                                     0x0654336c
8                                     0x065432b0
9                                     0x06545304
10                                    0x065426a4
11                                    0x0654212c
12                                    0x06540f8c
13                                    0x006b6cad
14  OfficeDrop Sync                   0x0000f894 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 164
15  OfficeDrop Sync                   0x00184ed4 mono_runtime_invoke + 68
16  OfficeDrop Sync                   0x001851af mono_runtime_delegate_invoke + 63
17  OfficeDrop Sync                   0x001b8f3f async_invoke_thread + 2799
18  OfficeDrop Sync                   0x001be46c start_wrapper + 348
19  OfficeDrop Sync                   0x001f060a thread_start_routine + 154
20  OfficeDrop Sync                   0x00217cf4 GC_start_routine + 100
21  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x96daced9 _pthread_start + 335
22  libsystem_c.dylib                 0x96db06de thread_start + 34

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x2bfff5 +com.officedrop.Sync.Mac (2.0.1 - 2.0.1) <943CAD79-B30C-3D5C-97EF-E2454D2FE6FC> /Users/some-user/Downloads/OfficeDrop Sync.app/Contents/MacOS/OfficeDrop Sync
0x91344000 - 0x91373ff7  libsystem_info.dylib (??? - ???) <37640811-445B-3BB7-9934-A7C99848250D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x96d50000 - 0x96e1bfff  libsystem_c.dylib (763.13.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <52421B00-79C8-3727-94DE-62F6820B9C31> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x9c7cf000 - 0x9c7edff7  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.32.7 - compatibility 1.0.0) <79179F83-457A-3539-A76B-E960D2108109> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
```

Comment: Funny, it works just fine for me.  What system version are you using?  And what does your call look like?